# Is the assignment @array = func(\@array) well behaved in perl?

Tags: perl

The title says it all: 
I am wondering whether perl statements like

```
@array = func(\@array);
```

always behave determinisitic in perl, i.e. whether the evaluation of the right hand side completes before anything is stored in @array on the left hand side. `func` is an arbitrary perl builtin or user defined function that may or may not modify @array passed by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `$x = some_combination_of_operators($x)` and `@a = some_combination_of_operators(@a)` are common practice.

The operand evaluation order of the assignment operators are not explicitly documented, but `my $x = $x;` and `local $x = $x;` are documented. As an another example, `@a = sort @a;` is not only common, it's optimized (to do the sort in-place). This demonstrates support for the construct in question. Even funky stuff like `($x,$y)=($y,$x);` is fully supported.

Finally, there's only one Perl compiler, which always produces the same result.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'@array = func(\@array);'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s                   \
4  <0> pushmark s                   |
5  <#> gv[*array] s                 |
6  <1> rv2av[t5] lKRM/1              > RHS of list assignment evaluated first
7  <1> srefgen sKM/1                |
8  <#> gv[*func] s/EARLYCV          |
9  <1> entersub[t6] lKS/TARG        /
a  <0> pushmark s                   \
b  <#> gv[*array] s                  > LHS of list assignment evaluated second
c  <1> rv2av[t2] lKRM*/1            /
d  <2> aassign[t7] vKS/COM_AGG
e  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: For the sake of consistence, shouldn't this be @a = f(\@a) in the first line?

Comment: @BarneySchmale, No. The question was not specifically about taking a reference, and neither is my answer. `f(@a)` can be `func(\@a)` or any other function.

Comment: Actually the question was about the case when @array is passed as a reference.

Comment: @BarneySchmale, "func is an arbitrary perl builtin"

Comment: "func is an arbitrary perl builtin or user defined function that may or may not modify @array passed by reference"

Comment: @BarneySchmale, Exactly. Again, if I made my answer as restrictive as you requested, it would not cover all that. Now, please stop spamming because I made the answer more useful than you want it to be.

Comment: @ikegami I too did not take your `func(@array)` as necessarily including `func(\@array)`

Comment: Yes everyone, functions can take references! Made clear in answer. @ysth